# Can someone explain why two trigonometric functions are equal when plotted, but not when put into the calculator?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, euclidean-geometry

I'm trying to find all the solutions to

$$
\sin(5a) = \cos(7a)
$$

My attempt is to use the identity $\sin a = \cos \frac{\pi}{2} -a$.

Setting $7a = \frac{\pi}{2} - 5a$, gives me $a = \frac{\pi}{24}$ and **one** solution is:

$$
\sin(5 \cdot \frac{\pi}{24} ) = cos(\frac{\pi}{2} - 5 \cdot \frac{\pi}{24})
$$

If I plug this into geogebra I get:

[image]

But if I put this into a calculater I get $\sin(5 \cdot \frac{\pi}{24} ) \approx 0.608 \text{ and }  cos(\frac{\pi}{2} - 5 \cdot \frac{\pi}{24}) \approx 0.1305$. I'm not very familliar with trig in general, but I was expecting them to be equal. What am I missing?

Comment: Maybe you just plugged it in wrong? I get 0.608 for both.

Comment: Gosh! You are right. Thanks!

Comment: It looks like you forgot the factor $5$ when you got the wrong result of $0.1305$.

Comment: Thats it. Thank you.